# Portable LaTeX?

Tags: tools, portability

This isn't explicitly a question on TeX syntax, but is there a program available (or a flag for latex itself) that will create a complete standalone LaTeX file from one that has multiple dependencies?

Comment: There is a very trivial solution. For example, if your top-level file is called `a.tex` you could create a file that has one line: `\input{a.tex}`. This is probably not what you mean. Besides that I don't know any solutions. Why do you need this?

Comment: Sorry for getting back you so late, @MarcvanDongen, but my ideal solution would resolve all `\input`s (even those hidden by `\usepackage`, using `makeatletter` and friend as necessary) to produce a single file to be processed by `latex` with a minimal TeX distribution.

Alternatively, something that compiles LaTeX to plain TeX would be pretty cool, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [bundledoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/bundledoc) and [arlatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/arlatex).

The `bundledoc` package builds an archive which contains all needed LaTeX files (`tex`, `cls`,...).

`arlatex` is a Perl-script based on `bundledoc` which generates a single `tex` file, which in return produces the other files by using `filecontents`.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume a few things:

- You are not doing something funny (with \write18, for example)
- The latex base format is ok for you (meaning you do not have to include it)
- The fonts do not have to be included

First of all, use the `\listfiles` command in the preamble.
The include all the latex files listed by this command into your file using the  `filecontents` package. Pray that my assumptions are ok to whatever non-god you have (the Leslie Lamport Lion?). Send the file.